# Make a grouped bar chart of this data

Tags: r, plot, graph

I was searching on this forum but every grouped bar chart I found was based on the grouping on a column. However I already used Java to combine my data, but I don't know how to plot this data in a grouped bar chart:
How I create the matrix (I wil omit all code to keep it simple):

```
MAT2 = matrix(data, ncol=2)
MAT2 = cbind(MAT2,kolommen)
colnames(MAT2) <- c("mpk6","mpk3","group")
```

which gives me:

```
       mpk6 mpk3 group                 
     [1,] "9"  "0"  "membrane"            
     [2,] "91" "64" "plastid"             
     [3,] "12" "0"  "extracellular region"
     [4,] "74" "21" "thylakoid"           
     [5,] "6"  "0"  "vacuole"             
     [6,] "21" "33" "cytosol"             
     [7,] "4"  "0"  "plasma membrane"     
     [8,] "9"  "12" "peroxisome"          
     [9,] "0"  "0"  "mitochondrion"       
    [10,] "22" "13" "nucleolus"           
    [11,] "0"  "0"  "ribosome"            
    [12,] "27" "31" "cell wall"
```

But when I plot this using barplot I get the following result:
[image]

The bars are grouped based on mpk6 and mpk3 but I want to group for "membrane","plastid","extracellular region" etc..:
[image]
I dont know if it possible but if it is it would be nice to just remove the bars of a height 0, so that there isn't that much whitespace in the graph(but maybe this will ruine the whole idea of the grouped bar chart, so if there are suggestions of the best option they are welcome!)

Comment: quite interesting to remove bars of height 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a data.frame called `A` or it can be coerced to a data.frame, here is my first guess using `tidyr`, `dplyr` and `ggplot2` libraries :

```
A <- gather(A, mpk, n, mpk6:mpk3)

ggplot(A %>% filter(n > 0) %>% mutate(group=droplevels(group)),
       aes(x=group, y=n, group=mpk, fill=mpk)) + 
geom_bar(position='dode', stat='identity') +
coord_flip()
```

The whitespace is no longer visible, but the width of each bar is fixed regardless of how many different mpk-n measurements are associated with it

[image: bar-plot of data supplied with variable width bars]

Another alternative is if you wish the widths of the bars to be the same (but there is more whitespace in the graph)

```
ggplot(A %>% filter(n > 0) %>% mutate(group=droplevels(group)) %>%
       group_by(group) %>% mutate(m=n()),
       aes(x=group, y=n, group=mpk, fill=mpk, width=0.9*m/max(m))) + 
geom_bar(position=position_dodge(width=0.9), stat='identity') +
coord_flip()
```

[image: alternative bar-plot of data with bar-width constant but whitespace appears when groups have different numbers of members as the distance between groups is constant]

Comment: It's not clear how you want the grouping to work, facet grid is how I've interpreted it, but you could easily have a combined chart using `position='dodge'` in `geom_bar()`

Comment: Thankyou, but I want them to be grouped as my second figure shown in the question, so blue for MPK6 en red for MPK3 e.g.

Comment: So not two seperate plots but actually the two plots you created combined into one

Comment: Just remove the facet grid command and then add in position=dodge. set fill=mpk to get the colors to differ across mpk. Updated answer with these changes.

Comment: I already have a matrix, do I have to do this step: "A <- gather(A,mpk,n,mpk3:mpk6)"? also you typed mpk in this, but which ot these two did you mean: mpk3 or mpk6? Thankyou for you help really appriciate ti!

Comment: You will need to have `tidyr` to perform that step - it's crucial to how i translate your data into a form for `ggplot`. `mpk` is just a dummy name for the column that the `gather()` creates, which will contain a factor with the levels `mpk3` and `mpk6` to indicate what kind of measurement the value `n` relates to. You probably want to read the documentation `?gather` as a starting point.

Comment: I just read it :) but running the gather code you provided gave me this warning: attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped

Comment: Oh, I think this is down to different data - for future reference, include the output of `dput(MAT2)` in your question so that it is easier for others. Try switching the order I put mpk3 and mpk6 in (i.e. mpk6:mpk3)

Comment: The warning didn't see to influence the output, thankyou for your help!